# How to get all field names from table using arcpy.ListFields?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, modelbuilder

I have a table:

[image]
,

Script at ModelBuilder's "calculate values":

Expression:

```
a("%path%")
```

Code BLOCK:

```
def a(path):
  fields = arcpy.ListFields(path,"FID_*")
  for field in fields:
    return field.name
```

Gives me only ONE field name!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. The `return` statement short-circuits it. Basic Python.

```
def a(path):
  field_names = []
  fields = arcpy.ListFields(path,"FID_*")
  for field in fields:
    field_names.append(field.name)
  return field_names
```

Though you may need to do it this way:

```
def a(path):
  field_names = []
  fields = arcpy.ListFields(path,"FID_*")
  for field in fields:
    field_names.append(field.name)
  return ";".join(field_names)
```

Comment: Just to reinforce that, when Python encounters a return statement, it will always exit the function, regardless of a loop.

Comment: I use arcpy.ListFields(fc,"*","All") where fc is the target feature class.

Answer (score 13):

```
    def getFieldNames(shp):
        fieldnames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp)]
        return fieldnames

    fieldnames = getFieldNames("country.shp")
```

returns a list of all fields of country.shp

Answer (score 0):

```
def a(path):
  fields = arcpy.ListFields(path,"FID_*")
  return fields
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python Script
# List all columns from every FC within a dataset
# GIS 10.1 SP 1, FGDB
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\NBU_GIS_10_1\NBU_GIS_10_1_GDB\NBU_GIS_10_1_GDB.gdb"

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
print datasets

for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        path = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, ds, fc)
        print path
        drive, path1, path2, GDB, dataset, fc = path.split('\\')
        print ("%(drive)s" % vars())
        print ("%(path1)s" % vars())
        print ("%(path2)s" % vars())
        print ("%(GDB)s" % vars())
        print ("%(dataset)s" % vars())
        print ("%(fc)s" % vars())
        path = drive + path1 + path2 + GDB + dataset + fc
        print path
        columns = drive + '\\' + path1 + '\\' + path2 + '\\' + GDB + '/' + dataset + '/' + fc
        print columns
        stuff = ("%(columns)s" % vars())
        fields = arcpy.ListFields("%(stuff)s" % vars())

        for field in fields:
            colmm = ("{0}".format(field.name))
            print ("%(colmm)s" % vars())
            columns = drive + '\\' + path1 + '\\' + path2 + '\\' + GDB + '/' + dataset + '/' + fc + '/' + ("%(colmm)s" % vars())
            print ("%(columns)s" % vars())
```

Comment: Highlight your code and press the { } button to format it correctly.

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a simple line for loop surch in accordance to the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfields.htm)

```
def fieldnames (dataset, sep=",", filter="*", fields_type="All"):
    """ Return Str of fields in a feature class, shapefile, or table
    in a specified dataset. The returned str can be limited with
    search criteria for name and field type and will contain field objects."""

    return sep.join(list([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(dataset, filter, fields_type)]))
```

and just call

```
fiednames("%path%", filter="FID_*")
```

You can also filter type or add more specific filter condition after with if contition in for loop

for exemple get only editable fields

```
def fieldnames(dataset, sep=",", wild_card="*", fields_type="All"):

    return sep.join(list([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(
        dataset, wild_card, fields_type) if f.editable]))
```

In this case you can ignore information fields automaticaly set by system has:

- FID OID OBJECTID
- creator date_cretor updater date_update (if you have active tracking change in database)
- GUID and GlobalID